# SharePoint BDC Model NULL Structure

Tags: crawling, fast-search, business-data-catalog

I crawl database with FAST Search Server for SharePoint 2010. When incremental crawl is running, it is getting the following error for some records. After the first error, SharePoint takes the same errors from every subsequent incremental crawl.

> SharePoint Log:
>
> 04/10/2012 18:56:12.21    mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)
>   0x1A04     Business Connectivity Services Business Data
>   ca7e Verbose      Instantiating  Type 'System.String'.  04/10/2012
>   18:56:12.21    mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)                       0x1A04
>   Business Connectivity Services Business Data                 ca7j
>   Verbose      Recursively instantiating Type 'System.String' at a nest
>   level of '0'.    04/10/2012 18:56:12.21    mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)
>   0x0580     SharePoint Server Search      Connector Framework
>   e64y Verbose      Getting the contents of entity instance with ID
>   Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.Identity    04/10/2012 18:56:12.21
>   mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)                       0x1A04     Business
>   Connectivity Services Business Data                  ca7l Verbose
>   Found primitive default value ''; returning that instead of
>   instantiating at a nest level of '0'.        04/10/2012 18:56:12.21
>   mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)                       0x1A04     Business
>   Connectivity Services Business Data                  ca7f Verbose
>   Completely instantiated Type 'System.String'.   04/10/2012 18:56:12.21
>   mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)                       0x1594     Business
>   Connectivity Services Business Data                 bix3 Medium
>   Closed connection to Db: FASTDB  04/10/2012 18:56:12.21    mssdmn.exe
>   (0x11C8)                       0x1594     SharePoint Server Search
>   FilterDaemon                  fld1 High         Fltrdmn: failure
>   reading ACL. Error 0x8004fd11
>   [fltrdaemon.cxx:2681] 
>   d:\office\source\search\native\mssdmn\fltrdaemon.cxx    04/10/2012
>   18:56:12.21    mssdmn.exe (0x11C8)                       0x1594
>   SharePoint Server Search      FilterDaemon                  e4ye High 
>   FLTRDMN: Errorinfo is "LobSystem (External System) returned a null
>   structure which is incompatible with the associated metadata." 
>   [fltrsink.cxx:553]  d:\office\source\search\native\mssdmn\fltrsink.cxx
>
> After the first error, every incremental crawle takes same Error which
>   is seen the following crawle history log table .
>
> 1. Crawle Log:
>
>    - **Crawle Type     :** Full
>    - **Successes     :**           284310
>    - **Warnings     :** 0
>    - **Errors                   :** 0
> 2. Crawle Log:
>
>    - **Crawle Type     :** Incremental
>    - **Successes     :**           25375
>    - **Warnings     :** 0
>    - **Errors                   :** 0
> 3. Crawle Log:
>
>    - **Crawle Type     :** Full
>    - **Successes     :**           20270
>    - **Warnings     :** 0
>    - **Errors                   :** 70
> 4. Crawle Log:
>
>    - **Crawle Type     :** Incremental
>    - **Successes     :**           12650
>    - **Warnings     :** 0
>    - **Errors                   :** 70
> 5. Crawle Log:
>
>    - **Crawle Type     :** Incremental
>    - **Successes     :**           26450
>    - **Warnings     :** 0
>    - **Errors                   :** 70
>
>      ```
>                      it continues like this.
>      ```

How can I solve this problem.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Please provide log for more details